# Save a collection in Unity with json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to serialize a collection. First I tried Unity's Json, then I switched to Newtonsoft. Newtonsoft worked in the editor, but wouldn't serialize when I built it as a UWP. Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated:

```
void SavePieces()
    {
        Collection<PieceData> PieceDataList = new Collection<PieceData>();

        Piece[] pieces = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Piece>();
        int i = 1;

        foreach (Piece piece in pieces)
        {
            if (piece.tag != "GamePiece")
                continue;

            PieceData tempPiece = new PieceData();

            tempPiece.PlayerId = piece.PlayerId;
            tempPiece.CurrentSpace = piece.CurrentSpace?.name;
            tempPiece.EndingSpace = piece.EndingSpace.name;
            tempPiece.StartingSpace = piece.StartingSpace.name;
            tempPiece.Parent = piece.MyPlayerStartArea.name;
            tempPiece.PieceStatus = piece.PieceStatus;
            tempPiece.PositionX = piece.transform.position.x;
            tempPiece.PositionY = piece.transform.position.y;

            PieceDataList.Add(tempPiece);

            i++;
        }

        var pieceJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PieceDataList, Formatting.Indented);

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("PieceData", pieceJson);
        Debug.Log("Player Prefs Pieces= " + PlayerPrefs.GetString("PieceData"));
    }
```

Here is My Struct:

```
[Serializable]
public struct PieceData
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentSpace { get; set; }
    public string EndingSpace { get; set; }
    public string StartingSpace { get; set; }
    public Piece.PieceState PieceStatus { get; set; }
    public bool IsHomePiece { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public float PositionX { get; set; }
    public float PositionY { get; set; }

    public PieceData(int playerId, string currentSpace, string endingSpace, string startingSpace, Piece.PieceState pieceStatus, bool isHomePiece, string parent, float x, float y)
    {
        PlayerId = playerId;
        CurrentSpace = currentSpace;
        EndingSpace = endingSpace;
        StartingSpace = startingSpace;
        PieceStatus = pieceStatus;
        IsHomePiece = isHomePiece;
        Parent = parent;
        PositionX = x;
        PositionY = y;

    }
}
```

Comment: Have You Tried JsonUtility?
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

Comment: could you post the errors you get when you build as uwp application? are you encountring build or runtime errors?

Comment: @QusaiAzzam JsonUtility is very bare bones and there are entirely legitimate reasons to use Json Dot Net instead of it. Say, if you want to serialize an object that references a singleton. Or a `List<ISomeInterface>` (where each item can be created from serializable information via a factory).

Comment: @Draco18s , That's what I'm trying to do. A collection of objects. I serialized the class that held all the properties, then I read somewhere that they couldn't be properties, and had to just be fields. It worked both ways in the editor, but when I built it as a UWP app, it froze up when it tried to save the collection to json in playerprefs. Just saving an object works fine in both, but not a collection. ):

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA , I'm not getting any errors that I can see. Just won't let me click on the screen after the save attempt.

Comment: "Collection of objects" can be serialized just fine by any automated serialization, provided that they're basically "data containers" (that is, they don't contain any references to things that are not data containers). It's the _references to things that are not data containers_ that JsonUtility cannot adequately serialize and deserialize (for example: Minecraft style `ItemStacks` which contain a reference to singleton-like `Item` instances which cannot be deserialized). I have a suspicion that your issue may be that you're stuffing the results into `PlayerPrefs` which was not meant to do this

Comment: Okay @Draco18s , but why would player prefs save it just fine when I run it in the editor? BTW, appreciate all the help.

Comment: I also just added my struct to the initial question if you need to look at it.

Comment: Don't know. Could be a size limitation that the editor doesn't have. Still though, don't use PlayerPrefs. Use a real file, it isn't that hard.

Comment: @Draco18s ,I'm just always afraid the device won't find it. Do you have an example of cross-platform storage you code show me, please?

Comment: That's what [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) is for.